# how to load Area Description File to Android Studio and retrieve the data from ADF to use in indoor navigation app?

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I'm a newbie to Augmented Reality. I am trying to create an indoor navigation application with Tango Project and Rajawali Engine.

I'm struggling at this point with the following:
- Adding a ADF file to Android Studio.
- Loading the ADF file within Android Studio, extracting the data from ADF file, and draw to the camera surface like this:

[image: This is an example]

Thank you for your help. I hope to receive an answer in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load ADF in android studio, ADF has to be used on a Tango device, and be loaded in Runtime.

Take a look of the [Java Area Description doc](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/java-area-learning) from Tango